# Python iterating over a dictionary and sending as a JSON

Tags: python

The below code only lists the first set of values from the dictionary as shown below. How to display all the values as JSON

```
{"born": 2000, "first": "John", "last": "Sam"}
```

```py
@cherrypy.expose
def values(self):
    docs = db.collection(u'users').stream()
    results = {}
    for doc in docs:
        results = json.dumps(doc.to_dict())
        print(results) # This prints all the values          
    return results  # This returns only the first set
```

There are many values in the database like this

```
{"born": 2000, "first": "James", "last": "tom"}
{"born": 2001, "first": "George", "last": "Kevin"}
```

Comment: `results` is overwritten in each iteration. You will have to use some collections to store before returning at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwritting `results` in each iteration. Try changing the code like this:

```
@cherrypy.expose
def values(self):
    docs = db.collection(u'users').stream()
    results = []
    for doc in docs:
        results.append(json.dumps(doc.to_dict()))
    print(results)    
    return results
```

Note that `results` is now a **list** where we **append** a dictionary in each iteration. Also, `print(results)` is now outside the loop, as otherwise it would print the results in each iteration.